# Forecast weather

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, weather-api

I use Google api for read weather and i learn it from [this post](http://icodeblog.com/2010/09/29/adding-local-weather-conditions-to-your-app-part-22-accessing-googles-xml-weather-api/) but now i want to  forecast weather for 2 days
does anybody have any idea about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305127/free-weather-api

Have a look at the above post.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [National Weather Service APIs](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/noaa-weather-service).